# Check if user is part of a manytomany relationship django

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have this model for a Set:

```
class Set(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 25)
    teacher = ForeignKey(get_user_model(), null = False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    students = ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name= 'set_students')
```

As you can see, the last field is a ManyToMany field. I need a queryset to get all the Sets that the user is part of.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can user reverse relation for current user `user`:

```
user.set_students.all()
```

Or with `Set.objects` by user_id:

```
Set.objects.filter(students__id=user.id)
```

Comment: Are both options equally efficient?

Comment: @FernandoJesusGarciaHipola I didn't make tests, so cannot say for sure. You can check are two queries identical by using queryset's `query` attribute. It will show raw SQL for both querysets.